# Sharing data between Angular 1 and Angular 2 apps

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-scope

This requires a bit of context:  I'm working on a legacy angular 1 app.  The front end is a bit of a monolith, and we'd like to upgrade to angular 2 without having to put all development on hold until it's rewritten.  We've identified a set of functionality that's independent from other parts of the app.  In a sense, it's like a function: If you pass in these inputs, it'll calculate it and return a result.  We'd like to bud this functionality off to its own code base and rewrite it as angular 2.

The way it works is, you login, all these calls are made to remote services, and their responses are stored in an angular 1 scope.  The functionality we'd like to bud off needs to be passed this data, but once it has it, it can do everything it needs to on its own.  So the question is, **how can I pass angular 1 data to an angular 2 app and vice versa?**  The two apps can be served from the same domain.

We've thought of using cookies, but for performance reasons, we don't want this data sent across the wire on every call.  We've thought about local storage, but I don't know much about it.  Not sure if it's a good fit or not.  Are there any other possibilities?  Anything built into angular 1/2 that could help with this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at ngUpgrade? It is a library provided with Angular that was designed specifically for this purpose: to allow communication between AngularJs (v1) and Angular v2+ apps. You can find out more here: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Another option can be to run either the AngularJS or the Angular 2+ app in an iframe within the other framework and use `window.postMessage(...)` to communicate between them both. However, it's not an ideal solution, as it requires both frameworks to be loaded and the communication between them both can be a bit messy.

You can read more about postMessage communication here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage